# How can I solve a problem I don't have any idea what to do with it like this?

Tags: exponential-function

if 
$$f(x)=\frac{4^{x}}{4^{x}+2}$$
, then
$$f(\frac{1}{11})+f(\frac{2}{11})+f(\frac{3}{11})+\cdots+f(\frac{10}{11})=?$$
By the way, I haven't taken calculus yet.

Comment: What kind of an answer do you expect here?

Comment: The answer of the question, and any idea on how to deal with these problems.

Comment: Hint: $$f(1-x) = \frac{4^{1-x}}{4^{1-x}+2} = \frac{2}{4^x + 2}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$f(x)=\frac{4^{x}}{4^{x}+2}=1-\frac{2}{4^{x}+2}=1-f(1-x)\implies f(x)+f(1-x)=1$$

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: Another hint: $1/11 + 10/11 = 1$.

Comment: @John Now I understand that $f(\frac{1}{11})+f(1 - \frac{1}{11})=1$, and the answer to my question will be $5$, but how can I figure this by my own?

Comment: OK, I think I got it now. Thanks for everyone helped me.

Comment: @OmarMohamedKhallaf It is a symmetry you can figure out by the graph which is true for any $f(x)=\frac{a^x}{a^x+\sqrt a}$ with $a>0$.